# Как стилизовать option под select?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Есть вот такой выпадающий список.

```css
select {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.joxi.ru/media/cache/preview/uploads/prod/2014/05/13/f8e/b5f/e82b8e0d4ed7fe4b8eaef79b94cff9022da760a7.jpg) no-repeat right center;
  background: url(http://cdn.joxi.ru/media/cache/preview/uploads/prod/2014/05/13/f8e/b5f/e82b8e0d4ed7fe4b8eaef79b94cff9022da760a7.jpg) no-repeat right center, -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #dbdbdb, #fafafa);
  background: url(http://cdn.joxi.ru/media/cache/preview/uploads/prod/2014/05/13/f8e/b5f/e82b8e0d4ed7fe4b8eaef79b94cff9022da760a7.jpg) no-repeat right center, -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #dbdbdb, #fafafa);
  background: url(http://cdn.joxi.ru/media/cache/preview/uploads/prod/2014/05/13/f8e/b5f/e82b8e0d4ed7fe4b8eaef79b94cff9022da760a7.jpg) no-repeat right center, -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #dbdbdb, #fafafa);
  background: url(http://cdn.joxi.ru/media/cache/preview/uploads/prod/2014/05/13/f8e/b5f/e82b8e0d4ed7fe4b8eaef79b94cff9022da760a7.jpg) no-repeat right center, -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #dbdbdb, #fafafa);
  background: url(http://cdn.joxi.ru/media/cache/preview/uploads/prod/2014/05/13/f8e/b5f/e82b8e0d4ed7fe4b8eaef79b94cff9022da760a7.jpg) no-repeat right center, linear-gradient(bottom, #dbdbdb, #fafafa);
  border: 1px solid #797a7c;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

*[Пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29FTZ/)*

Вопросы:

1. Как сделать, чтобы ширина опций была равна ширине стилизованного селекта?
2. Как убрать обводку вокруг всех опций?

Хотелось бы решить данные вопросы на чистом *CSS*, либо с минимальным внедрением *JavaScript (jQuery)*.

Comment: К сожалению не поддаются CSS селекты)
По ссылке статья, там как раз об этом и вариант решения проблемы.
http://dimox.name/styling-select-boxes-using-jquery-css/

Использование плагинов jquery допустимо?

Comment: Вообще, конечно, желательно все это решить без сторонних плагинов. По сути, возникает только эти 2 проблемы, со стилизацией каждой отдельной опции проблем не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/8vFLy/3/

```js
$("#current_option").click(function(){
    customOptionsBlock = $("#custom_options");
    if (customOptionsBlock.is(":hidden")) {
        $("#custom_options").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#custom_options").hide();
    }
});

$("#custom_options li").click(function(){
    choosenValue = $(this).attr("data-value");
    $("select").val(choosenValue).prop("selected", true);
    $("#current_option span").text($(this).text());
    $("#current_option").attr("data-value", choosenValue);
});
```

```css
#custom_select {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#current_option {
    width: 100%;
    background: #d2d2d2;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    line-height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#current_option:hover {
    background: #EBEBEB;
}

#current_option b{
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

#current_option b img{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#custom_options {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -2px;
    background: #EBEBEB;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

#custom_options li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

#custom_options li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

#custom_options li:first-child {
    margin-top: 4px;
}

#custom_options li:hover{
    background: #d2d2d2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="">--------</option>
    <option value="1">Opt1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt3</option>
</select>

<div id="custom_select">
    <div id="current_option" data-value="">
        <span>------------</span>
        <b><img src="http://support.eye.fi/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/arrow-down.png.pagespeed.ce.sb6_oS5SGc.png"/></b>
    </div>
        <ul id="custom_options">
            <li data-value="">----------</li>
            <li data-value="1">Opt1</li>
            <li data-value="2">Opt2</li>
            <li data-value="3">Opt3</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Тут есть селект настоящий и полностью с ним синхронизированных кастомный. В роли аттрибута value выступает у кастомного data-value.

Comment: Идею понял. Предположим, я создам свой собственный селект. Чтобы передать необходимые данные на сервер, мне нужно создать нормальный селект с такими же значениями, скрыть его и синхронизировать со своим?

Comment: Ну да, смотря как передаются данные, если это ajax запрос и данные собираются вручную, то можно и не создавать обычный, а если это классическая форма, с кнопкой submit, то, конечно, удобно синхронизировать и отправлять данные с формы, как всегда это делается.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8vFLy/5/ с JQuery 1.10.1 не работало в опере. С 2.1.0 - все ок.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы при клике вне области нашего псевдоселекта он закрывался?

Comment: Переписал ваш код - http://jsfiddle.net/8vFLy/6/
Работает, начиная с версии 1.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Доделал, чтобы работало и в обратном направлении. Например, для случаев, когда этот селект загружается со значением.

```js
$("#current_option").click(function() {
  customOptionsBlock = $("#custom_options");
  if (customOptionsBlock.is(":hidden")) {
    $("#custom_options").show();
  } else {
    $("#custom_options").hide();
  }
});

$("#custom_options li").click(function() {
  choosenValue = $(this).attr("data-value");
  $("select").val(choosenValue).prop("selected", true);
  $("#current_option span").text($(this).text());
  $("#current_option").attr("data-value", choosenValue);
});

$('select').change(function() {
  $('#current_option').attr("data-value", $(this).val());
  $("#current_option span").text($('select :selected').text());
});
```

```css
#custom_select {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
#current_option {
  width: 100%;
  background: #d2d2d2;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  line-height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#current_option:hover {
  background: #EBEBEB;
}
#current_option b {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
#current_option b img {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#custom_options {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background: #EBEBEB;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
#custom_options li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
#custom_options li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
#custom_options li:first-child {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
#custom_options li:hover {
  background: #d2d2d2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">--------</option>
  <option value="1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt2</option>
  <option value="3">Opt3</option>
</select>

<div id="custom_select">
  <div id="current_option" data-value="">
    <span>------------</span>
    <b><img src="http://support.eye.fi/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/arrow-down.png.pagespeed.ce.sb6_oS5SGc.png"/></b>
  </div>
  <ul id="custom_options">
    <li data-value="">----------</li>
    <li data-value="1">Opt1</li>
    <li data-value="2">Opt2</li>
    <li data-value="3">Opt3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```